# Как с помощь CrudRepository сделать возврат нескольких значений?

Tags: java, spring

У меня есть такой репозиторий:

```
public interface MessageRepository extends CrudRepository<Message, Long> {  

}
```

Мне надо сделать такой запрос:

```
select status, count(status)
from message
group by status
```

который возвращается что-то типа:

```
"NEW";13
"sent";13
"SUCCESS";18
"delivered";14
```

Могу я как-то это сделать это за одно действие (единственным методом в репозитории) ?

Answer (score 0):

Аннотация [@Query со строковым запросом](https://dzone.com/articles/adding-queries-spring-data-jpa) или [JPA с магией Criteria API](https://spring.io/blog/2011/04/26/advanced-spring-data-jpa-specifications-and-querydsl/).